# How to make extension for Customizable websites?

Tags: script, browser-addons, website

I want to write an addon/extension/script that allows me to hide specific parts of a website and remember these preferences. The next time I visit the website, this content should be hidden from me.Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What browser are you using? [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) sounds like it might be what you want if you are on Firefox.

Comment: @ChrisN: Greasemonkey allows userscripts for firefox. Userscripts are supported by chrome and opera by default, so every modern browser should be fine.

Comment: You can hide web elements with addons like uBlock Origin.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are userscripts. [userscripts.org](http://www.userscripts.org/) has a collection of scripts for Greasemonkey on Firefox that may possibly work in Chrome or Opera.

If you want to write your own, here are some resources:

- [wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual).
- [The Beginners Guide to Greasemonkey Scripting](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/internet/the-beginners-guide-to-greasemonkey-scripting-598247)
- [Writing your first Greasemonkey Script](http://htmlblog.net/writing-your-first-greasemonkey-script-adding-menus-to-facebooks-top-menu/)

[One thing to note for Chrome: It seems Google has pulled support for installing userscripts except from trusted sources.](http://userscripts.org/topics/113176)